# GWT ListBox - how to have a listbox item disabled?

Tags: dom, gwt, listbox

How can I have the first item in a listbox disabled? Following is my code:

```
ListBox list  = new ListBox();
list.addItem("Select an item");
list.addItem("a");
list.addItem("b");
list.addItem("c");
```

How do I disable the first item in list?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could select the  first child element and set the disabled atribute:

```
list.getElement().getFirstChildElement().setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Instead of doing DOM manipulation, do:
list.getElement().<SelectElement>cast().getOptions().getItem(0).setDisabled(true);

Answer (score 16):

For anyone who finds this page and is looking to disable a GWT ListBox option which is NOT the first option in the ListBox, this worked for me:

```
list.getElement().getElementsByTagName("option").getItem(itemNumber).setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Where itemNumber is the option you would like to disable.

Answer (score 5):

```
list.getElement().<SelectElement>cast().getOptions().getItem(0).setDisabled(true‌​);
```

Answer (score 3):

On six lines:

```
 private void disableOption(ListBox listBox, int optionNumber, boolean disable){
      if(optionNumber<=listBox.getElement().getChildCount()){
            Element element = listBox.getElement().getFirstChildElement();
            while (--optionNumber > 0){
                element = element.getNextSiblingElement();
            }
            element.setAttribute("disabled", disable ? "true" : "false");
      }
 }
```

Comment: Shouldnt be there (optionNumber-- > 0) instead of (--optionNumber > 0)?