# How to add option to dropdown but only use it for display

Tags: gwt, listbox

I need to add a label (called Title) to a dropdown in GWT. The label 'Title' can appear in the list of options but if 'Title is selected, it should not persist to the database, or just pass null instead of 'Title'. Can I do this using ValueListBox?

Comment: [GWT ListBox - how to have a listbox item disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269878/gwt-listbox-how-to-have-a-listbox-item-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Disable it:

```
list.getElement().getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
```

Unless its really necessary it becomes null?